# Change public post to private

Tags: privacy

I posted some items that I only wanted invited family and friends to see.  But these mistakenly were posted publically.  How do I remove these from public viewing?

Comment: Simply update these posts and change their post status to`private`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this with plugins or PHP. To do it without any modification to the system, you should mark the post's visibility as "Private" and then only Admins or Editors can see it. You must in this case, make your friends and family "editors", which you can do in the "Users" tab in the Dashboard.